# Why context menu not work for android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, contextmenu

I have a simple android application, In my application, there is one image icon, and when I click the icon, I want to show context menu. My code is debugging but when I click the image button, nothing change, so context menu not work, I do not know where is the problem, Any idea will be appreciated.

**MenuFragment:**

```
class MenuFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false)

    popupMenu()
    }

  private  fun popupMenu() {
   val popupMenu = PopupMenu(requireContext(), menu)
   popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu)
   popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
       when(it.itemId) {
           R.id.menu_one -> {
               Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "menu1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               true
           }
           R.id.menu_two -> {
               Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "menu2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               true
           }
           else -> true
       }
   }
   menu.setOnLongClickListener {
       try {
           val popup = PopupMenu::class.java.getDeclaredField("mPopup")
           popup.isAccessible = true
           val menu = popup.get(popupMenu)
           menu.javaClass
               .getDeclaredMethod("setForceShowIcon",Boolean::class.java)
               .invoke(menu, true)
       }catch(e: Exception) {
           e.printStackTrace()
       }finally {
           popupMenu.show()
       }
       true
   }
   }

  }
```

**fragment_menu:**

```
         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
            android:text="5:33 PM"
            android:textSize="12sp"
          />
```

**menu:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_one"
    android:title="Menu1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_one"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_two"
    android:title="Menu2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_two"
    />
```

Comment: You placed popupMenu() function after return statement, so, popupMenu() never calls.

Comment: @SergeyO, put where ?

Comment: You can override fragment's onViewCreated() callback and place popupMenu() function to it.

Comment: @SergeyO, is it possible give solution?

Comment: override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false)
    }

    
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        popupMenu()
    }

Comment: @SergeyO, sorry, I get it now, tnx :)

Comment: You shouldn't show things before the view is created; it might work, but it is by base counter logic and adds a potential crash just because. As far as I remember, pop-menu uses another view as an anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to show the menu as soon as possible, since the function invocation is after the return statement then it never happen.

You have to leverage the fragment lifecycle. Override `onViewCreated` and call it there

```
override... onViewCreated(...) {
     super....
      popUpMenu()
}
```

The method `onViewCreated` happens immediately after the view is created. If you need it when the view is ready to interact `onStart`. In both cases, make sure backward navigation doesn't show it again by mistake.

Comment: Tnx so much as in comment mentioned I solve it,  but this answer will help others people also,  tnx so much

Comment: @cutico do have any idea for this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/68246003/10991969